# BASICのCVI,CVSやMKS$の関数処理について

Tags: basic

30年前くらいに、N88-BASICで動かしていたソースコードを動かす必要があり、「N88互換BASIC for Windows95」を使用しています。

CVI,CVSやMKS$の関数には対応していないらしく、コードが動きません。以下のような処理をしたいのですが、CVI,CVSやMKS$の処理に代わる処理方法をご存じの方がいましたら、教えて頂けますと有難く存じます。

記

・CVI

```
 Nz(I,J)=CVI(MID$(P,J1,2)) AND &HFFF

 Nz(I,J+1)=CVI(MID$(P,J1+1,2))/&H10
```

・CVS

```
 W1=CVS(MID$(P$,J1,4))
```

・MKS$

```
 LSET SOLF$(J,L)=MKS$(SOL(J,L))
```

Comment: 単に `double` や `int` の入出力関数だから、既にデータファイルがあってそれを読み書きする必要が**ない**のなら好きに自作すればいいんです。

Comment: ここ [ダウンロード N88互換BASIC for Windows95](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/dl/win95/prog/se055956.html) を見ると23年前のフリーソフトで当時でも出来そうに無い記事 [ｎ88baicについて](https://okwave.jp/qa/q102446.html) があります。検索するとこんな商業ソフト [BASIC/98](https://www.dennougumi.co.jp/products/basic98/ver5/index.html) があり、パンフレット [PDF版カタログダウンロード(1,837KBytes)](https://www.dennougumi.co.jp/products/basic98/ver5/ver5.pdf) の最後には該当の命令がサポートされている記載があるので、こちらに切り替えた方が良いのでは？

Comment: 元のファイルが文字化けしたランダムファイルでしたので、変換処理でファイル内容を明らかにしようとしていました。BASIC/98も参考にしたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

`CVI` `CVS` `CVD` は `MKI$` `MKS$` `MKD$` の逆の変換です。 `MKI$` `MKS$` `MKD$` はそれぞれ整数値、単精度実数値、倍精度実数値をその**内部表現どおり**に文字列 (バイト列) に置き換えます。

つまり例えば `cvi("ab")` に対応するのは

```
10 x$="ab"
20 print asc(mid$(x$,1,1))+asc(mid$(x$,2,1))*256
```

というような処理です。

実数 (浮動小数点) の場合は内部表現が少し複雑ですが形式は [IEEE 754](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) のはずなのでこれに基づいて変換処理を書けるでしょう。

Comment: ASC処理は知りませんでした。試してみたところ、数字が表示されました。これから改善してみたいと思います。